# Installing freenect_stack from source

Tags: ros, catkin, libfreenect, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded the source code for freenect_stack from git to the src folder of my catkin workspace. When I tried to build it using catkin_make, I got the following error:

```
*-- +++ processing catkin package: 'freenect_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(freenect_stack/freenect_camera)
*CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/devel/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:
    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake
    camera_info_manager-config.cmake*
  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  freenect_stack/freenect_camera/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed*
```

What is the camera_info_make config file? And how do I get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67797/installing-freenect_stack-from-source/) by [Qandeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5107/qandeel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[camera_info_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) is a ROS package on which freenect_stack depends. You need to either install it on your system or add it to your catkin workspace.

To install on Ubuntu for Groovy:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-camera-info-manager
```

If you decide not to build freenect_stack yourself, you can install it similarly:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-freenect-stack
```

**Note**: the [freenect_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_camera) package has other dependencies you will probably also need for building freenect_stack.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2